# Problemas com SSH ao executar tutorial do Hadoop

Tags: ssh

Estou precisando processar uns arquivos bem grandes e para isso estou experimentando usar o Hadoop (na versão 2.4.1).

Não estou conseguindo executar o tutorial oficial num Ubuntu 14.04 (64 bits) e Java (Oracle versão 1.7.0_60-b19). [Quando iniciando o DFS](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Execution), mesmo tendo configurado o SSH como especificado, o retorno é o seguinte:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ???: Name or service not known
```

Como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta em uma outro post ([no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326274)): o problema parece estar relacionado com o fato das bibliotecas padrão do Hadoop serem para arquiteturas 32-bits.

Algumas respostas apontam para a possibilidade de recompilar as coisas, mas algo bem mais simples resolveu pra mim: criar variáveis de ambiente que configuram corretamente o Hadoop e estas bibliotecas nativas.

- Adicione duas novas variáveis ao seu arquivo **etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh**

  ```
  export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=${HADOOP_PREFIX}/lib/native
  export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_PREFIX/lib"
  ```